# Corresponding java datatype for Numeric(9,2) in sybase

Tags: java, sybase

I want to insert a Numeric(9,2)value through SP in Sybase which is being invoked through Java.
What data type should I use in java side.

Comment: Why do you not provide the information requested in your old question?

Comment: Use BigDecimal if you want to store real numbers. But your use case is to store the currency data, use integer/long to store and handle precision point conversion at java side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have to write an application to use data stored on database I suggest you to search for the default data type mapping of the jdbc driver you have to use (it depends on target database).

In your situation you could check this data type mapping http://jtds.sourceforge.net/typemap.html. For numeric the default is BigDecimal. In my experience BigDecimal saves some headaches.